# Adding HtmlHelper NameSpace in Web.Config does not work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor, html-helper

### Problem No 1:

I have started learning ASP.NET MVC. I have made a simple extension method, like this:

```
namespace MvcTestz  //Project is also named as "MvcTestz"
{
  public static class SubmitButtonHelper //extension method.
  {
    public static string SubmitButton(this HtmlHelper helper,string buttonText)
    {
        return string.Format("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"{0}\">",buttonText);
    }
  }
}
```

Then I have added namespace of the Custom HtmlHelper in to the `Web.Config` ,like this

```
  <namespaces>
    <!--other namespaces-->
    <add namespace="MvcTestz"/>
    <!--other namespaces-->
  </namespaces>
```

So that I could use intellisense in the razor View ,but it custom Helper didnt showed up in  one View `(Home/View/About.cshtml)`.
[image]

So in another view `(Home/View/Index.cshtml)` I added namespace by `@using MvcTestz;` statement.

### Problem No 2:

Upon WebApp execution Home page`(Home/View/Index.cshtml)` shows input button text without rendering it into HTML.

[image]
On the About page `(Home/View/About.cshtml)` sever generates error. [(Click for Enlarged)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vJJw.jpg)
[image]

### Update:

1. Intellisense problem solved , I had to edit the Web.Config present in the View Directory. SOLVED.
2. `HtmlString` Should be used if I want to render a Html button. SOLVED.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Problem 1:**

Razor namespaces should be registred in the `<system.web.webPages.razor>` node in web.config:

```
 <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="MvcTestz"/>

      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

**Problem 2:** Use `HtmlString` instead of string in your helper:

```
public static HtmlString SubmitButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string buttonText)
{
    return new HtmlString(string.Format("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"{0}\">", buttonText));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,

For your extension method, use `MvcHtmlString.Create`

```
public static MvcHtmlString MySubmitButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string buttonText)
{
  return MvcHtmlString.Create("<input type='submit' value='" + buttonText + "' />");
}
```

and to include your reference see below

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <namespaces>
        <!- add here.....  -->
        <add namespace="MvcTestz"/>

      </namespaces>        
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Comment: Thanx for the help Yasser bhai

Comment: you made my day by calling me "bhai" :)